# Boost error when building Openpose on ubuntu16.04

Tags: boost, cmake, ubuntu-16.04, openpose

I am trying to build [openpose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose) on my ubuntu16.04 server, following the guide [here](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/blob/master/doc/installation.md). When I go to call `make` in the `build` directory, my results have this error:

```
[ 12%] Performing configure step for 'openpose_lib'
CMake Warning (dev) at cmake/Misc.cmake:32 (set):
  implicitly converting 'BOOLEAN' to 'STRING' type.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:165 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system thread filesystem) (found suitable
  version "1.58.0", minimum required is "1.54")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:458 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2177 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:8 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:49 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/build.make:126: recipe for target 'caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-configure' failed
make[2]: *** [caffe/src/openpose_lib-stamp/openpose_lib-configure] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/openpose_lib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm a little confused; it says it has found Boost `1.58.0` and that the minimum required is `1.54`, but then says that it `Could NOT find Boost`.

Let me know if you have any advice.
Thanks!

Comment: The error states that it found Boost on your system, but not some of the specific Boost libraries (for the correct architecture/compiler). You can add `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` to when you run `cmake` to print out debug information about how CMake is locating Boost. You can check, for example, does the `filesystem` Boost library exist on your system?

Comment: Hmm, how do I check if it has the filesystem lib? I looked in my `/usr/include/boost` and there's both a `filesystem/` and `filesystem.hpp`, so I think it does.

Also, I tried running `cmake -DBoost_DEBUG=ON ..` but got the message 
`CMake Warning:
  Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

    Boost_DEBUG
`

Comment: The filesystem library itself will have a .so file extension and will likely be located in a lib or lib64 folder.

Comment: Thanks; I looked in both the lib folders and there are no files containing `boost` or `filesystem`; should I just do an install of `boost 1.58.0` then? I'm a little confused because it *looks* like my system already has boost installed but it obviously doesn't

Comment: Boost has headers and many different libraries associated with it; I'm not sure what parts of Boost you have installed. You can try manually installing the parts you need (e.g. `sudo apt-get install libboost-filesystem1.58-dev`), or maybe try installing everything `libboost-all-dev`.